# Conditionally add RouterLink or other attribute directives to an element in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 if I have an element like `<button></button>` how can I conditionally add an attribute directive like `[routerLink]="['SomeRoute']` to it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no straight way to do this. There are some workarounds... I used something like this:

```
<button *ngIf="condition" [routerLink]="['SomeRoute']"></button>
<button *ngIf="!condition"></button>
```

There is an similar discussion here: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6576)

Comment: What if you want to display it even if there is no routing?

Comment: I think @fifix is the best practice for this question.

Answer (score 192):

Or you can simply add a condition to the attribute.

```
<button [routerLink]="myVar ? ['/myScreen'] : []"></button>
```

Redirect to '/myScreen' only if myVar is true.

Comment: probably for some older Angular version was OK, in my 2.4.8 this  `<a [routerLink]="true?[]:['/route','id']" >test</a>` shows `/route/id`

Comment: In Angular 4 this results in an `href` value of `/` when it's not desired.

Comment: I am doing the same thing
`<a [routerLink]="menuItem.isDisabled ? [] : [menuItem.path]" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
       [class.disabled]="menuItem.isDisabled">....</a>`

But I get the following error on page load:
**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'undefined'**

Comment: This worked... :\
`<a [routerLink]="menuItem.isDisabled ? null : menuItem.path" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
       [class.disabled]="menuItem.isDisabled">...
    </a>`

Comment: I got an issue like..
Navigate only based on a observable variable (async) response.

Please guide me in implementation.

Comment: This fires a click on Angular 8, a click I have no clue how to was handled, nothing happened, except that child component emitted a new observed value

Comment: This does not remove the href in Angular 8, so it's not acceptable.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to duplicate the element, and just want to prevent clicks depending on the condition, you could do the following:

```
<button 
  [style.pointer-events]="condition ? 'auto' : 'none'" 
  routerLink="/some/route"
>
</button>
```

Comment: This is fine if you don't need to hide links from external crawlers (i.e Googlebot) but just prevent users from clicking it.

Comment: this is very smart!

Comment: please notice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36987506/2511298

Comment: brilliant answer

Answer (score 4):

```
   <div [ngClass] ='{"disabled-link":!isMicrositeEnable,"cursor-pointer":"isMicrositeEnable"}' [routerLink]="isMicrositeEnable ? ['/microsite'] : []">
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a working sample. When you need to bring more than one condition you can have inner condition as follows

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" [routerLink]="app.treatment === 'X' ? ['/route1', app._id] : app.treatment === 'Y' ? ['/route2', app._id] : ['/route3', app._id] ">Go</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a detail. Try to avoid using buttons for navigation. Screenreaders wont understand that its a navigation out of the box. You will now need to add an aria-label that tells the screenreaders what it does. This adds more code. But the simple solution would be to add the [routerLink] to an anchor link. Then style it as a button. But I prefer to use the standard blue links because people usually knows what will happen then. ex: I would never try to rightclick on a button and open it in a new tab. So: buttons for operations and anchorlinks for navigation

Comment: This is a misleading answer. Buttons can be used for navigation since navigation does not always mean an element is a link. It's perfectly ok to use buttons for dropdown navigation, popup menus, etc. (that's still "navigation").

Comment: @SimonRabbit how do you make your buttons accessible for screen readers?

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way to do this is wrapping your condition inside of a ternary operator like this:

```
<button [routerLink]="(myVar ? if_true : if_not_true)"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Angular 10:

```
<button routerLink="{{MyVar == true ? '/route/' + item.id : '/same/route'}}"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a button with routerLink. A would use an anchorlink styled as a button to do it. The button element is for operations and anchors is for routing/navigate.
Below code will tell the browser/screenreaders etc. what it is.

```
<a *ngIf="condition" class="make_it_look_like_a_button" [routerLink]="['somehere']">test</a>
<button *ngIf="!condition">Test</button>
```

The link case above will have 'open in new tab...' when right clicking it. But a drawback is that hardly no one would think of it when it is style as a button.