# Angular2, what is the correct way to disable an anchor element?

Tags: html, dom, typescript, angular, angular2-template

I'm working on an **Angular2** application, and I need to display -- but `disable` an `<a>` *HTML* element. What is the correct way to do this?

**Updated**

Please note the `*ngFor`, this would prevent the option of using `*ngIf` and not rendering the `<a>` altogether.

```
<a *ngFor="let link of links"
   href="#" 
   [class.disabled]="isDisabled(link)" 
   (click)="onClick(link)">
   {{ link.name }}
</a>
```

The **TypeScript** component has a method that looks like this:

```
onClick(link: LinkObj) {
    // Do something relevant with the object... 
    return false;
}
```

I need to actually prevent the element from being clickable, not just appear that it is with the **CSS**. I was assuming that I needed to potentially bind to the `[disabled]` attribute at first, but this is incorrect as the anchor element doesn't have a `disabled` property.

I looked at and considered using the `pointer-events: none` but this prevents my style of `cursor: not-allowed` from working -- and this is part of the requirement.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Specifying `pointer-events: none` in CSS disables mouse input but doesn't disable keyboard input. For example, the user can still tab to the link and "click" it by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or (in Windows) the <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd> key. You could disable specific keystrokes by intercepting the `keydown` event, but this would likely confuse users relying on assistive technologies.

Probably the best way to disable a link is to remove its `href` attribute, making it a non-link. You can do this dynamically with a conditional `href` attribute binding:

```html
<a *ngFor="let link of links"
   [attr.href]="isDisabled(link) ? null : '#'"
   [class.disabled]="isDisabled(link)"
   (click)="!isDisabled(link) && onClick(link)">
   {{ link.name }}
</a>
```

Or, as in Günter Zöchbauer's answer, you can create two links, one normal and one disabled, and use `*ngIf` to show one or the other:

```
<ng-template ngFor #link [ngForOf]="links">
    <a *ngIf="!isDisabled(link)" href="#" (click)="onClick(link)">{{ link.name }}</a>
    <a *ngIf="isDisabled(link)" class="disabled">{{ link.name }}</a>
</ng-template>
```

Here's some CSS to make the link look disabled:

```css
a.disabled {
    color: gray;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Even the the `<a>` element lacks an `href` it is still clickable, I just verified this...what now?  Still not perfect.

Comment: @DavidPine: I've updated my answer to handle the `click` event.

Comment: the BIG disadvantage you will lose the SEO on this process, have a look: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74032/what-is-the-seo-impact-of-using-an-anchor-tag-without-a-href-attribute

Comment: You can also use `[attr.disabled]="isDisabled(link)"` in <a> tag.

Comment: @Sriram: **Do not** use `[attr.disabled]` on an `<a>` tag. It's not standards compliant and only works in Internet Explorer, not in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: just a note: dont call functions in angular from template in attributes like ngIf, its performance issue, as they are called x-times each seccond, unless the components cd strategy is on push. Use properties, or directive or mentioned cd strategy.

Answer (score 38):

For `[routerLink]` you can use:

Adding this CSS should do what you want:

```
a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: not-allowed; 
}
```

This should fix the issue mentioned by @MichelLiu in the comments:

```
<a href="#" [class.disabled]="isDisabled(link)"
    (keydown.enter)="!isDisabled(link)">{{ link.name }}</a>
```

Another approach

```
<a [routerLink]="['Other']" *ngIf="!isDisabled(link)">{{ link.name }}</a>
<a  *ngIf="isDisabled(link)">{{ link.name }}</a>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4KJPEW?p=preview)

Comment: So I wouldn't want to bind to `[disabled]`, why not?

Comment: The user can still tab to the link and press Enter.

Comment: @MichaelLiu interesting So it would also require `(focus)="isDisabled(link) ? false : true"`

Comment: `(focus)="false"` doesn't seem to prevent the user from tabbing to the link, at least in Chrome.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Getting closer, but I still need the style of the anchor to be `cursor: not-allowed` when it is disabled.

Comment: I'll have look when I'm back on the computer.

Comment: Seems I misinterpreted your question a bit. I tried to fix it for `[routerLink]` which is a bit different than for normal anchor elements. @MichaelLiu approach breaks the [routerLink] though, therefore my approach might provide some value as well.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When you set `pointer-events` to none, cursor styles are not applied. So you can use either one of those both together they make no sense.

Comment: Is this the same behabior in all browsers? AFAIR it differs.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Every Angular question I have searched for on SO, you have answered! Nice work!

Comment: @JMK thanks :D It was fun. Sadly not that much time anymore.

Answer (score 9):

My answer might be late for this post. It can be achieved through inline css within anchor tag only.

`<a [routerLink]="['/user']" [style.pointer-events]="isDisabled ?'none':'auto'">click-label</a>`

Considering `isDisabled` is a property in component which can be `true` or `false`.

Plunker for it: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/TOh8LM/

Comment: I do not believe this is correct. Angular still propagates the (click) binding, as such it would still occur. Please create a plunker with this and share it here.

Comment: @DavidPine I add one plunker for it. https://embed.plnkr.co/TOh8LM/  I just gave reference for href tag in that, similarly it can work with `routerLink` directive within anchor tag

Answer (score 7):

consider the following solution

```
.disable-anchor-tag { 
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just came across this question, and wanted to suggest an alternate approach.

In the markup the OP provided, there is a click event binding. This makes me think that the elements are being used as "buttons". If that is the case, they could be marked up as `<button>` elements and styled like links, if that is the look you desire. (For example, Bootstrap has a built-in "link" button style, https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#examples)

This has several direct and indirect benefits. It allows you to bind to the `disabled` property, which when set will disable mouse and keyboard events automatically. It lets you style the disabled state based on the disabled attribute, so you don't have to also manipulate the element's class. It is also better for accessibility.

For a good write-up about when to use buttons and when to use links, see [Links are not buttons. Neither are DIVs and SPANs](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: Seems the simplest to me without having to play css and javascript games. Of course, it requires that you use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

```
   .disabled{ pointer-events: none }
```

will disable the click event, but not the tab event. To disable the tab event, you can set the tabindex to -1 if the disable flag is true.

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [class.disabled]="isDisabled">
     <a [routerLink]="['link']" tabindex="{{isDisabled?-1:0}}" > Menu Item</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for anchor tags that act as tabs:

```
[ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': isSaving ? 'none': 'auto'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of class.disabled, we can also bind a variable with the disabled attribute.  This will be used only buttons, inputs and dropdowns. [HTML disabled Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp)

For Example:

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled">Test</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yywxtf?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used

```
tabindex="{{isEditedParaOrder?-1:0}}" 
[style.pointer-events]="isEditedParaOrder ?'none':'auto'"
```

in my anchor tag so that they can not move to anchor tag by using tab to use "enter" key and also pointer itself we are setting to 'none' based on property 'isEditedParaO
rder' whi

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to disable anchor tags:

```
[style.pointer-events]="condition ?'none':'auto'"
```

Comment: Please do not revert edits that objectively improve the post. In this case, I added code formatting and corrected your English without changing the meaning or intent of your post. See [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](/help/editing).

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
<a [attr.disabled]="someCondition ? true: null"></a>
```

Comment: As a word of explanation about why folk likely voted down this seemingly good answer it does not add `disabled` to the anchor element (I wish it did!) but rather adds `disabled="true"`.

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
<a [ngClass]="{'disabled': your_condition}"> This a tag is disabled</a>
```

Example:

```
 <a [ngClass]="{'disabled': name=='junaid'}"> This a tag is disabled</a>
```

Comment: This does not work, while it will make it appear to be disabled - it is in fact still clickable, thus not at all solving the problem.

Comment: Here is the correct answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36987506/2410379