# Preventing routerLink Changing Routes with click Event Handler

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My angular application contains an anchor tag which has a `routerLink` and `click` handler associated with it:

```
<a [routerLink]="/abc" (click)="onClick"> </a>
```

I would like the `routerLink` to be used when the user right-clicks and selects "Open in New Tab".

The `click` handler should be triggered if the user simply left-clicks on the link. In this case I do **NOT** want the `routerLink` to trigger a route change.

Within my click handler I have tried aborting the click event, i.e.

```
public onClick(event: MouseEvent): {
    // Was hoping this would do it...
    event.preventDefault();
    // .. clutching at straws
    event.stopPropagation();
    // .. oh dear oh dear. Still not working
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

None of these are preventing the `routerLink` from activating and navigating the the new route `/abc`. How can I have my `click` handler prevent the `routerLink` from being fired?

Comment: Have you tried to add `target="_blank"`? to make it always open in a new tab? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985112/angular2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-disable-an-anchor-element

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That is not my desired behavior. I do *NOT* want to open the route if the user left-clicks on the link (in a new tab or otherwise).

Comment: But you do want to open in a new tab using right-click?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Only if the user picks "Open in New Tab" from the context menu (or similar, depending on browser)

Comment: You might consider implementing your custom `RouterLink` directive derived from the integrated one.

Comment: I too appear to have this issue, yet it seems to work fine with material designs approach within the  _haltDisabledEvents function, which from what I can tell is the exact same approach being used here. 

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/31b30fce08e79955d6650fc7581a0cf7a6b22113/src/material/button/button.ts#L175

Comment: Any specific reason you must have both `[routerLink]` **and** `(click)`? Seems more flexible to inject the `Router` service into your component, then in your click handler use `router.navigate()` conditionally.

Comment: Have you tried using href instead of routerLink? The execution order might be different and make preventDefault() work

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manually handle the navigation on `<a>` click then remove `routerLink` directive in your template.

```
<a href=# (click)="onClick"> </a>
```

notice above `href=#` is used because, it will simulate as if nothing changed in regards to link, i.e you will still see the pointer on hover like on normal `<a>` otherwise you can omit this and add your custom class.

instead in your `onClick` handle it appropriately.

```
constructor(private router:Router){}

public onClick(){

// Handle routing here or whatever behavior you want
this.router.navigate(['./abc']);

}
```