# [attr.disabled]="true" does not working in anchor tag

Tags: angular, typescript, attributes, anchor

Why `[attr.disabled]="true"` does not working in anchor tag?

### component:

```
this.isHold=true;
```

### html:

```
<a (click)="showDialogToHold()" href="Javascript:void(0);" class="a-l2-link 
img-space" icon="fa-angle-right" [attr.disabled]="isHold">Hold</a>
```

I also tried `[disabled]="isHold"`. But `[disabled]` does not support for anchor tag. it's throwing this error `Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'a'` related with [Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'li'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241135/cant-bind-to-disabled-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-li)

Comment: You can't disable `<a>`! Probably you can add some styling to make it look disabled like `text-decoration:none`, `cursor:default` and `color:grey`!

Comment: I want disable the link based on user role. how can I do it for my situation?

Comment: My sugestion is: don't show the links to user if he/she is not authorized!

Comment: But my design looks like ugly, if am using show/hide. any ideas?

Comment: along with the styles mentioned by @DhavalMarthak add     pointer-events: none;

Comment: @selvassn can you provide it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks in html. Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a. Hence you can use css to achieve this.

CSS Code :

```css
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:default;
    color:grey;
    pointer-events:none;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
   .disabled {
           pointer-events: none !important;
           cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<a (click)="showDialogToHold()" href="Javascript:void(0);" class="a-l2-link 
img-space" icon="fa-angle-right" [ngStyle]="{ 'disabled ': isHold }">Hold</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
  <a (click)="showDialogToHold()" href="Javascript:void(0);" class="a-l2-link 
    img-space" icon="fa-angle-right" disabled={{isHold}}>Hold</a>
```

Comment: is it support angular 2?

Comment: yes, its support angular

Comment: Nope. it's not working