# How do you make an <a> link disabled using condition?

Tags: html, angular

I use angular 4 how can I disable the `<a>` element with a condition doing something like this `[disabled]="!f.form.valid"`

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" 
        href="https://mailtrap.io/inboxes/354346/messages" 
        target="_blank" (click)=f.form.reset() > Verify your Email Now</a>
```

If you suggest to just use the link button so I want to konw how to add  `target="_blank"`

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Right now it doesn't make much sense. Your title asks how to disable an anchor (`<a>`), but then you ask about adding `target="_blank"`. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry, I just want one of them if i use the <a> how i can disable it and if i use button how can i add the target

Comment: @mplungjan - I think that the correct duplicate is [Angular2, what is the correct way to disable an anchor element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36985112/1009922).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to styles to [this excellent post in css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/).

```
.isDisabled {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

<a [ngClass]="{'isDisabled':condition}"
   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled" 
   href="https://mailtrap.io/inboxes/354346/messages" 
   target="_blank" (click)=f.form.reset() > Verify your Email Now</a>
```

Comment: That would just make it appear disabled. If you want to go only CSS add `pointer-events: none`. I would recommend stopping the event in JavaScript though.

Comment: @Phix You are absolute right. I missed that.

Comment: This is still not the right solution as the link is still tabable.