# Disabled button is still clickable in angular material

Tags: angular, material-design

```
<a  md-icon-button [routerLink]="['./new']" queryParamsHandling="merge"
                mdTooltip="Add Document" [disabled]="isAddButtonDisabled(selectedAssociation)">
                <md-icon>add</md-icon>
            </a>
```

The button is firing click event even when the button is disabled. Is there a way to prevent the click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links)

Comment: hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985112/angular2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-disable-an-anchor-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the achor tag - try to hide the anchor tag by wrapping it inside a div or use css to disable the anchor tag

Whereas `[disabled]` is a property binding it can hold only a property value - you are trying to bind a function to it - I'm not sure this will work - please check

Happy coding !!

Answer (score -2):

Try this CSS rule:

```css
[disabled]{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This will only change the cursors appearance, it won't prevent any click events

Comment: Yep, accidentally removed the wrong line when pasted my code. Thanks!