# Adding routerLink to anchor tag dynamically based on if a router link is passed to component

Tags: angular

I am trying to add `routerLink` to an anchor tag dynamically based on if a `routerLink` is passed to the component itself.

This is the code I currently have:

```
[attr.routerLink]="router ? router : null"
```

The resulting markup looks like this when a `routerLink` is passed, but no `href` is passed:

```
<a _ngcontent-hlo-122="" routerlink="/myRoute">My Link</a>
```

I've tried this out a number of ways, but I can never seem to get this to work. Does anyone have a solid solution to this problem?

Comment: routerLink is an angular directive not element property.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I've tried this with a ternary operator as well, but there is not a value to put on the other side that doesn't throw an error when the routerLink passed to the component is null, undefined, or not valid. `[attr.routerLink]="router ? router : null"`

Comment: AFAIK you can't apply `routerLink` conditionally.  I've managed to workaround this using the @Gunter's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431188/angular-2-disable-routerlink)

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753819/conditionally-add-routerlink-or-other-attribute-directives-to-an-element-in-angu).

Solution:

```
<a [routerLink]="router ? [router] : []>My Router Link</a>
```