# Ternary operator with `routerLink` inside the template

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Do you know how to use the ternary operator with `routerLink`?

Now it is like so:

```
<ion-button *ngIf="event?.evId"
      routerLink="/event/event-details/{{event?.evId}}">
            Cancel
</ion-button>

<ion-button *ngIf="!event?.evId" routerLink="/event"> Cancel
 </ion-button>
```

I would like to use the ternary operator here and remove one section completely. How to do that?

`Note` I can do that inside the TS file. But how to do that without using the TS file?

Comment: What is  wrong with `event?.evId ? '/event/event-details/event?.evId'  :  '/event'`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi No. It is not working. It takes URL like so: url: `event/event-details/event%3F.evId`

Comment: How about this:  `[routerLink]="event?.evId ?  ['/event/event-details/event?.evId'] : [' '/event']"`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753819/conditionally-add-routerlink-or-other-attribute-directives-to-an-element-in-angu) the second answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OP's**

```
  <ion-button [routerLink]="event?.evId ? '/event/event-details/'+ event?.evId : '/event'"> 
       Cancel
   </ion-button>
```

**Original**

You can [bind to any attribute](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#types-of-data-binding) like this

```
[routerLink]="event?.evId != null ? '/event/event-details/'+event.evId : '/event' "
```

Comment: No. It is not working. It takes URL like so: `url: "event/event-details/event%3F.evId"`

Comment: sorry, I updated my answer, I missed something, included the property accessor within the string.