# Angular: how to stop router-link when I am directed to another page

Tags: angular

I am creating a CRUD application. I would like to know how do I break router-link when I click the view-student button.

Furthermore, it is possible to show the title only on the first page, so once you press the view-student button to delete the title too?

Thank you all from the heart

```js
div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-primary text-white">
<h1>Welcome, click on the button below to see all students!</h1>
</div>

<div  class="container-fluid">  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">  
    <ul class="navbar-nav">  
      <li class="nav-item ">  
        <a routerLink="view-student" class="nav-link" class="btn btn-primary active" role="button" >View Student</a>  
      </li>   
    </ul>  
  </nav>     
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try to explain further what you want to achieve? Specifically, what you mean by "stop" or "break" router link.

Comment: Does the following question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753819/conditionally-add-routerlink-or-other-attribute-directives-to-an-element-in-angu

Comment: @Clashsoft when I click on the view customer button I don't want the view-customer link to appear again

Comment: @misha130 that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: I put the image to understand what I am looking for

Comment: So you want to hide the link/button/anchor tag alltogether? You could use `routerLinkActive="d-none"` - this conditionally applies the `d-none` CSS class if the routerLink is currently active. `d-none` means `display: none;` in Bootstrap.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that this is usually not done in navbars, because it is confusing UX.